# Django delete folder when session ends

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am creating a directory using the session key and uploading files to it. I want to delete this directory once the user ends the session by closing the tab.

```
    def upload_pdf(self, request, form):
        files       = form.cleaned_data["file_field"]
        # Get or Create Directory
        Path(f'{PDF_PATH}{request.session.session_key}').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for f in files:
            try:
                pdf_handler = PdfWriter()
                pdf_handler.append(f)
                file_path = f'{PDF_PATH}{request.session.session_key}/{f}'
                pdf_handler.write(file_path)
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f'<b>{f}</b> Uploaded <a href="my-file-view/{file_path}/" target="_blank">View</a>')
            except:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, f"<b>{f}</b> not Uploaded - not a PDF file")

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How can I run a command at session close?

Comment: You don't know when the session ends. If a user closes the page, that does not send anything to the server. Eventually the session will be outdated, and removed, so you can add a remove signal on the `Session`, although even that is probably circumvented when the sessions are removed in bulk.

Comment: So I should either change the way I handle file uploads or use cronjobs to monitor sessions?